# CameraX - VideoCaptureConfig.Builder is showing an error

Tags: android, video-capture, android-camerax

I have the following line in my `CameraXFragment` and Android Studio is showing me an error:

```
videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()     // <--- Builder is in red
            .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
            .setCameraSelector(cameraSelector)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .build()
```

Android Studio does not recognize `Builder` after updating the `camerax` version from `'1.0.0-beta04'` to `'1.0.0-beta12'`.

Does somebody know how to create a `VideoCaptureConfig` in the latest version ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `VideoCapture.Builder()`:

```
videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
            .setCameraSelector(cameraSelector)
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .build()
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use this in order to utilize the library's restricted api. That doesn't mean it's gonna work, though.

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question. He ask about how to create a `VideoCaptureConfig`